# Why in finding target path of shortcut with shell link in c++ it refers to windows\installer folder

Tags: c++, windows, shortcut

I want to find target path of a shortcut in startmenu folder ,
I know that should use from shell link component object model ,
But in my test for some shortcuts it shows:

***"windows\installer\{guid}\x.exe***"

and does not show program files folder for it , and for other shortcut works fine,
How can i find target path for these products.
this is the function i use:

```
    HRESULT TargetShortcut::ResolveIt(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR lpszLinkFile, LPTSTR lpszPath, int iPathBufferSize)
    {
        HRESULT hres;

        if (lpszPath == NULL)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        *lpszPath = 0;

        // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
        // has already been called.
        IShellLink* __psl = NULL;
        HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
        {
            // Get a pointer to the IPersistFile interface.
            IPersistFile* ppf = NULL;
            hres = __psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&ppf);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
            {
                // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar
                // for success.

                // Load the shortcut.
    #ifdef _UNICODE
                hres = ppf->Load(lpszLinkFile, STGM_READ);
    #else
                WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH] = {0};
                // Ensure that the string is Unicode.
                MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, lpszLinkFile, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH);
                hres = ppf->Load(wsz, STGM_READ);
    #endif

                if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
                {
                    // Resolve the link.
                    hres = __psl->Resolve(hwnd, 0);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
                    {
                        // Get the path to the link target.
                        TCHAR szGotPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
                        hres = __psl->GetPath(szGotPath, _countof(szGotPath), NULL, SLGP_SHORTPATH);

                        if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
                        {
                            hres = StringCbCopy(lpszPath, iPathBufferSize, szGotPath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Release the pointer to the IPersistFile interface.
                ppf->Release();
            }

            // Release the pointer to the IShellLink interface.
            __psl->Release();
        }
        return hres;
    }
```

and this an answer for a shortcut :

```
       C:\Windows\Installer{53FA9A9F-3C19-4D43-AD6B-DEF365D469BA}
```

Comment: Is this the path to the Camtasia installer or is the match of the UUID just a coincidence?

Comment: Not all shortcuts refer to files on the disk. For example, you can have shortcuts to Web sites or shortcuts to Control Panel items. These shortcuts do not have the `SFGAO_FILESYSTEM` attribute. If you ask for the path even though it's not a file on disk, they will make up an artificial path. That's what you're getting here. It's the artificial path for a dynamically-installed program.

Comment: @HelloWorld : it was a coincidence only

Comment: @Raymond Chen : But when I double click on a shortcut in startmenu folder the program runs. How windows understands the real paths from these artificial paths?

Comment: When you double-click the shortcut, the shortcut's handler goes to work and figures out what program you're running, installs/updates the program if necessary, and then runs it. (Note that if the program is install-on-demand it doesn't have a real path yet.) If you want to do all that yourself, you can ask MSI.

Answer (score 1):

Try first this code:

```
#include "msi.h"

#pragma comment (lib, "msi")

...
TCHAR Path[MAX_PATH];
Path[0] = '\0';            
TCHAR pszComponentCode[MAX_FEATURE_CHARS+1];
TCHAR pszProductCode[MAX_FEATURE_CHARS+1];
pszComponentCode[0] = _T('\0');
pszProductCode[0] = _T('\0');

if ( MsiGetShortcutTarget(pszLinkPathName, pszProductCode, NULL, pszComponentCode) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    DWORD dw = MAX_PATH;
    UINT ret = MsiGetComponentPath(pszProductCode, pszComponentCode, Path, &dw);
    //Path now contains path to EXE
}
else
{
   //process regular LNK
}
```

Then in ELSE part you can call code to resolve regular LNK

Comment: You may want to highlight to the person asking the important part of the code they should modify/update